# JSLint confusion in Javascript alerts are not declared

Tags: javascript, loops, syntax, ecmascript-6, jslint

Hey so I'm using JSLint under the assumption I'm using a browser and tolerating multiple vars and whitespace mess.
The whole program works, but  I have a few problems, according to JSLint. First off, I'm trying to use alert(string) to make pop-up error messages, but JSLint is telling me the alerts are undeclared, I haven't found a resource on the internet that's explained how to make this not happen yet.

Secondly, I have loops that look like this:

```
function setMixedList() {
  "use strict";
  clearResults(); 
  var n = "0";
  var l = "0";
  var text = "";
  while (n < numList.length && l < letList.length) {
    document.getElementById("listInput").value = 
    text += numList[n] + letList[l];
    n ++;
    l ++;
  }
```

This loop in particular takes two separate arrays and mixes them together in order; one containing numbers (1-7) and the other containing letters (a-g) in a way so they appear in a text box like this:

```
1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d 5 e 6 f 7 g
```

JSLint doesn't like two things about this. The first is that in the

```
 document.getElementById("listInput").value = 
        text += numList[n] + letList[l];
```

section of the loop, JSLint tells me the "+=" is unexpected. When I edit that to:

```
text = text + numList[n] + letList[l];
```

JSLint tells me the "=" is unexpected and I'm not sure how to take these things out without making my program unable to work.

The other important part of this is the

```
n ++;
l ++;
```

section of code. I know JSLint doesn't like ++, but if I make the code

```
n+= 1;
l+= 1;
```

The string doesn't come out right, with some characters undefined because I'm not just dealing with numbers. Anybody know how to fix these problems?

Comment: Why are you incrementing a string?

Comment: I'm too new to JS to know what's wrong with what I'm doing

Comment: You should have the `text += numList[n] + letList[l];` part in the loop, then `document.getElementById("listInput").value = text;` *after* the loop.

Comment: Thank you nnnnnn, that helped me with the += problems.

Comment: Can no one help me with the undeclared alerts?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part

> JSLint is telling me the alert

This can be resolved by following one of the way . In `jslint` options set 
`"devel:true"` which will enables things like Alert, console,prompt.Check this [link](http://jshint.com/docs/options/) to know more about it.

Secondly set `browser` option set to `true` in your .`jshintrc` and use `window.alert` instead of `alert`

Comment: Considering the task I have to complete, I can't set the "in development" assumption to "true". Also, using window.alert makes JSLint tell me now that the window is undefined.